# Why can't std::string be the last named argument before '...'?

Tags: c++, formatting

I have a function `formatToStr()` which receives a format in `const std::string&` and returns the formatted string.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdarg>

std::string formatToStr(const std::string& format, ...) {

        char buff[1024];
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format.c_str());
        vsnprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), format.c_str(), args);
        va_end(args);
        return std::string(buff);
}

int main() {

        printf("Testing: %s\n", formatToStr(std::string("test")).c_str());
        return 0;
}
```

This code compiles with a warning:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
...
$ g++ ./c.cpp 
./c.cpp: In function ‘std::string formatToStr(const string&, ...)’:
./c.cpp:8:9: warning: second parameter of ‘va_start’ not last named argument [-Wvarargs]
    8 |         va_start(args, format.c_str());
      |         ^~~~~~~~
```

When changing `format` type to `const char*` there's no warning.

Why is that?
Thanks.

Comment: do not tag `C` for quesitons about C++ code. Do not confuse C++ with C, they are two different languages. In C++ you would use a variadic template to implement a variadic function. `va_args` is ancient, arcane and easy to get wrong

Comment: `format.c_str()` is not the name of any of `formatToStr`'s arguments. `va_start` needs the *name* of an argument. (And that argument can't be a reference.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat But then you'll see (or should see) the next revelation: *warning : passing an object of reference type to 'va_start' has undefined behavior [-Wvarargs]*

Comment: @AdrianMole Hmm. I didn't get the warning (with `-Wall -pedantic`). Something else I have to enable?

Comment: You can't use a reference for the last named parameter https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/cstdarg.syn#1.sentence-4 - make it a string view (passed by value) if you wish to maintain reference semantics.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Dunno. I got that from clang, which is famously good for spotting UB. MSVC goes further and gives an error: *error C2338: static_assert failed: 'va_start argument must not have reference type and must not be parenthesized'*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You slightly misinterpret the error message. The culprit is not the `last named argument` but the `second parameter`: `format.c_str()` is not `format`. `va_start` is a macro, it needs the name of the last named argument.

However, as mentioned in comments, `va_start(args,format)` would be wrong too, because you may not use a reference here, see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/cstdarg.syn#1.sentence-4. It is undefined. Some compilers diagnose it (but others dont). You could use a `string_view` passed by value.

Last but not least, `va_args` is basically outdated since C++11 introduced [variadic templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). And for formatting of strings via `%s`-like formatters you should take a look at [`<format>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/format).